# Images not displaying on test run in any browser

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am importing images to be on a page as links - everything lines up perfectly on Dreamweaver, however the images are not being found when i test the page - what am i doing wrong

here is the code im using

```
<pre><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/backup/Desktop/SweetreeInkWeb/STIpngButtons/OrderButton.png" name="order" 
width="230" height="30" id="order"></pre>
```

Comment: Couple of things... 1: You need to define a site in DW and then use that. I wouldn't absolutely link an image like that. 2: You need to post your CSS since you have added the CSS tag (it will also help identify the issue).

Comment: how do i define a pre existing document?

Comment: CSS is as follows

<style type="text/css">

body {
 background-color: #000;
 background-image: url(../sweetreeinkwebpage/backgrounds/index.png);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
</style>

Comment: is it a hosted website? if so, can you upload images to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your linking to a file on your computer - the link should be relative (or absolute) to your web root folder. (ex. "/STIpngButtons/OrderButton.png")

<strike>Web pages does not have access to files that resides on a users computer.</strike> 
**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, if you using your computer as a server, or opening the file locally, loading a file like this should work.

Try setting the path of the file to a relative or absolute url (based on where the page is rendered from)

ex:

```
<img src="/STIpngButtons/OrderButton.png" />
```

What is the error your getting from Developer tools (F12 in chrome)
Could be a misnamed path as well.

Comment: Unless the OP is using their computer as a server and in which case he can.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your CSS has an image linked (so that shows me the path to use...):

```
<pre><img src="../sweetreeinkwebpage/STIpngButtons/OrderButton.png" name="order" 
width="230" height="30" id="order"></pre>
```

That should work for you in this case. If Intellisense generated that URL in the CSS, your site is already defined. I'll bet that's why the image didn't load.

If your image isn't located in this **particular** folder, then make the folder and move your image there.